# Image height match container

Tags: html, css

How can I make the image always contain perfectly inside the container as the exact same height and width?

```css
.container {
  width: 500px!important;
  height: 800px!important;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
}

.content_holder {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5%;
}

.custom_container .content_holder h3 {
  color: #fff!important;
}

.custom_container .content_holder p {
  color: #fff!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <img src="http://wrighthand.uk.w3pcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/shutterstock_1016869756.jpg" />
  <div class="content_holder">
    <p>Subject</p>
    <h3>Container Title</h3>
    <a class="button">Learn more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```

For some reason the image doesn't sit in the container like on the website i tried to add it to.

http://wrighthand.uk.w3pcloud.com

Comment: you can use [`object-fit`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/object-fit) but you would need a [polyfill](https://github.com/bfred-it/object-fit-images) for ie

Comment: So your goal is, to make the img have 100% width/height of .container and fill it?

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```css
.container {
  width: 500px!important;
  height: 800px!important;
}

.container:before {
 content: "";
 background: rgba(0,0,0,0.2);
 top: 0;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 right: 0;
 position: absolute;
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
}

.content_holder {
 position: absolute;
 bottom: 0;
 padding: 5%;
}

.custom_container .content_holder h3 {
 color:#fff!important;
}

.custom_container .content_holder p {
 color:#fff!important;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<img src="http://wrighthand.uk.w3pcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/shutterstock_1016869756.jpg" width="100%" height="100%"/>
<div class="content_holder">
<p>Subject</p>
<h3>Container Title</h3>
<a class="button">Learn more</a>
</div>
</div>
```

It now fits perfectly. (It's a bit distorted, however...)

Answer (score 0):

You can put your image as a `background` of the container and then use background positioning properties such as,

```
  background-image: url('http://wrighthand.uk.w3pcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/shutterstock_1016869756.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
```

```css
.container {
  width: 500px;
  height: 800px;
  background-image: url('http://wrighthand.uk.w3pcloud.com/wp-content/uploads/2018/03/shutterstock_1016869756.jpg');
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  background-size: cover;
  background-position: center;
  position: relative;
}

.container:before {
  content: "";
  background: rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2);
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  bottom: 0;
  right: 0;
  position: absolute;
}

.content_holder {
  position: absolute;
  bottom: 0;
  padding: 5%;
  color: #fff;
}

a {
  color: inherit;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
  <div class="content_holder">
    <p>Subject</p>
    <h3>Container Title</h3>
    <a class="button">Learn more</a>
  </div>
</div>
```